# How 震え出してしまう should be translated?

Tags: meaning, translation

I mean 震え出す translates as "to **begin** to tremble" and meaning of しまう auxilary verb is "to finish ...,  to do ... completely".

So, it doesn't make sense for me to complete something you begin to do...

Comment: What's the subject belonging to that verb? You should include some context. BTW, しまう can be used in [more ways](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86-te-shimau-%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%86-meaning/) than you seem to realize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

しまう has quite a few meanings, e.g. finish doing something, do something completely, thoroughly, accidentally, regrettably, unexpectedly, or involuntarily, etc...

震えだしてしまう can be "start shivering" + "do...involuntarily/unexpectedly". Does it make sense in your context?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.